# How to demote foreground service to background, removing service notification

Tags: android

I run a service in the foreground in `onPause()`, and wish to demote the service back to the background in `onResume()` such that the required service notification disappears.

The idea is that the service will be bound to the app while the app is visible, and will run in the background, and when the app is not visible, the service will run in the foreground and the user will see and interact with the foreground service notification which will control a MediaPlayer.

I know `startForeground()` will foreground the service, but how do I background a service?

```
private void notify(NotificationCompat.Builder builder)
{
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    // keep service running in foreground or will be killed
    startForeground (NOTIFICATION_ID,  notification);
}
```

Comment: `stopForeground()` ?

Comment: yeah that looks like it thx